# google charts with two curves not aligned with the time

Tags: google-visualization

I want to display 2 curves. To show temperatures in 2 rooms. 
X-axis is the time.
The time is at the level of the minute.
so I see the chart for one day.
THe temeprature is logged when it changes only.
So if the temperature is the same during 12 hours, I have no value during 12 hours.
It means thet temperature of the 2 rooms is not reported at the same time.
With google chart I have to do something like:

- time, temp_room1,temp_room2
- 08:01AM, 19, 20
- 10:33AM, 18, 20
- 11:00AM, 18, 21

However, when I read my data, at 10:33AM I have a value reported for temp_room1 only since the temperature did not change in room2.
So If I follow google chart rule, I have to set the temperature of room2 to the previously known temperature for this room! This is cumbersome.

Do I have another means?
I was thinking about this:

- 08:01AM, 19, 20
- 10:33AM, 18,
- 11:00AM, , 21

Which is easy for me, it is natural as it maps to the reality (the log I have out of my database).
Any idea?

thanks,
rod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to set the value for room 2 at 10:33AM, just use `null`, and the in the chart's options, set the `interpolateNulls` option to `true`.